# Create a new column based in criteria in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
         DATE FOLIO_ID        LAT  ...  DIA HORA         CIUDAD_APROXIMADA
0  11/01/2018   D00001  22.768507  ...    4   15  SAN NICOLAS DE LOS GARZA
1  26/02/2018   D00009  25.708889  ...    1    2  SAN NICOLAS DE LOS GARZA
2  01/01/2018   D00014  25.647176  ...    1    4                 GUADALUPE
3  01/01/2018   D00017  25.714607  ...    1    5  SAN NICOLAS DE LOS GARZA
4  01/01/2018   D00018  25.492993  ...    1    9                  SANTIAGO
```

I want to create a new column that is called `PERIODO_DIA` which based on `HORA` fills like this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

for i in df["HORA"]:
    if 6< i < 11:
       df["PERIODO_DIA"] = 1

   elif 12 < i < 20:
      df["PERIODO_DIA"] = 2

   elif 21 < i < 24:
     df["PERIODO_DIA"] = 3

   else:
     df["PERIODO_DIA"] = 4
```

So the code iterates over every row of the data frame checking every value from HORA and assigns a value for PERIODO_DIA based on that.

So far I've tried different loops but I cant figure the logic out

Comment: God, I'm sorry. Edit done, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your periods are not continuous (i.e., you skip some hours of the day and group them all in `4`), you cannot use [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html). But you can solve this with a simple loop

```
df['PERIODO_DIA'] = 4
for i, (start, end) in enumerate([(6, 11), (12, 20), (21,24)]):
    df.loc[df.HORA.gt(start) & df.HORA.lt(end), 'PERIODO_DIA'] = i+1
```

Or create a dictionary with all 24 hours as keys and the period as the values (`mapper = {0: 4, 1: 4, ..., 7: 1, ..., 23: 4}`) and use `df.map`

```
df['PERIODO_DIA'] = df.HORA.map(mapper)
```